# How to notify property changed from delegate and update UI

Tags: wpf, events, mvvm, delegates, caliburn.micro

I'm using caliburn micro in a wpf app in which I have a list and detail viewmodels and their views side by side.  Select an item from the list on the left and see the detail on the right in the detail vm.

If the detail `IsDirty` (changed, not saved) and they select a new item from the list, I want to notify the user of that fact.  I have that working fine.  But if the user clicks "no" to stay on their dirty item, I want the list view to stay on their current item.  Here's what I have so far:

`ListViewModel`:

```vb
    Private _selectedItem As Library.VEntityStatusInfo
    Public Property SelectedItem As Library.VEntityStatusInfo
        Get
            Return _selectedItem
        End Get
        Set(value As Library.VEntityStatusInfo)
            Events.Publish(New SelectionChangingEvent With {.Sender = Me,
                                                            .Identification = value.Identification,
                                                            .Callback = Sub(id As Integer)
                                                                            _selectedItem = (From m In Model Where m.Identification = id).FirstOrDefault
                                                                            NotifyOfPropertyChange(Function() SelectedItem)
                                                                        End Sub})
        End Set
    End Property
```

`DetailViewModel`:

```vb
Public Sub Handle(message As SelectionChangingEvent) Implements IHandle(Of SelectionChangingEvent).Handle
    If TryCast(message.Sender, EntityList.EntityListViewModel) Is Nothing Then Return

    If Me.Model Is Nothing OrElse Me.Model.Identification <> message.Identification Then
        CanChange(message.Identification, message.Callback)
    End If
End Sub

Private Sub CanChange(identification As Integer, eventCallback As System.Action(Of Integer))
    If Me.Model IsNot Nothing AndAlso Me.Model.IsDirty Then
        Dialogs.ShowMessageBox(
            "You have unsaved data.  Are you sure you want to change employee's?  All changes will be lost.",
            "Unsaved Changes",
            MessageBoxOptions.YesNo,
            Sub(box)
                If box.WasSelected(MessageBoxOptions.Yes) Then
                    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(identification) Then
                        Me.Model = Nothing
                        Me.OnRefreshed()
                    Else
                        BeginRefresh("GetByIdentificationAsync", identification)
                    End If
                    eventCallback(identification)
                Else
                    eventCallback(Model.Identification)
                End If
            End Sub)
    Else
        eventCallback(identification)
        BeginRefresh("GetByIdentificationAsync", identification)
    End If
End Sub
```

`SelectedItem` is bound to the `ListBox` `SelectedItem` and that works properly.  When I put breakpoints in each step, they were all hit, including the property `Get` after `NotifyOfPropertyChanged`.  But the UI fails to update.